# Django JSON field - query id field

Tags: python, json, django, mariadb, django-orm

I am trying to filter a Django JSONfield (MariaDB backend, Django 4.0)

**target_360** is the **JSON field**, every query I've tried brings back an empty queryset, even though the debug statement clearly shows the matching id in the first row of the 'parent' query

field in models.py  using django.models.JSONField

```
target_360 = models.JSONField(_('360 target'),default=None, null=True)
```

Query Code

```py
surveys_with_target = Survey_Instance.objects.filter(pulse_id=pulse_id, survey_id=survey_id, target_360__isnull=False)
logger.debug('First row target_360')
logger.debug(surveys_with_target[0].target_360)

logger.debug('target_id in filter')
logger.debug(target_id)
survey_test = surveys_with_target.filter(target_360__contains=target_id)
logger.debug("SURVEY TEST:")
logger.debug(survey_test)
survey_test = surveys_with_target.filter(target_360__id__contains=target_id)
logger.debug("SURVEY TEST 2:")
logger.debug(survey_test)
survey_test = surveys_with_target.filter(target_360__id=target_id)
logger.debug("SURVEY TEST 3:")
logger.debug(survey_test)
```

edit - added some more tests:

```
  logger.debug("SURVEY TEST 4")
        survey_test = surveys_with_target.filter(target_360__contains={'id':target_id})
        logger.debug(survey_test)
        logger.debug("SURVEY TEST 5")
        survey_test = surveys_with_target.filter(target_360__contains={"id": "189f5422-f522-4860-8794-a3375f84a086"})
        logger.debug(survey_test)
        logger.debug("SURVEY TEST 6")
        survey_test = surveys_with_target.filter(target_360__contains={"id": target_id})
        logger.debug(survey_test)
        logger.debug("SURVEY TEST 7")
        survey_test = surveys_with_target.filter(target_360__contains="189f5422-f522-4860-8794-a3375f84a086")
        logger.debug(survey_test)
        logger.debug("SURVEY TEST 8")
        survey_test = surveys_with_target.filter(target_360__has_key="id")
        logger.debug(survey_test)
```

debug output:

```
First row target_360
{"id": "189f5422-f522-4860-8794-a3375f84a086", "target_type": "Individual"}
target_id in filter
189f5422-f522-4860-8794-a3375f84a086
SURVEY TEST:
<QuerySet []>
SURVEY TEST 2:
<QuerySet []>
SURVEY TEST 3:
<QuerySet []>
SURVEY TEST 4
<QuerySet []>
SURVEY TEST 5
<QuerySet []>
SURVEY TEST 6
<QuerySet []>
SURVEY TEST 7
<QuerySet []>
SURVEY TEST 8
<QuerySet []>
```

It's probably something really simple, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You were about there to the solution. Give this a try

```py
survey_test = surveys_with_target.filter(target_360__contains={'id':target_id})
# the above query will find all the target_360 results with the give target id.
```

For more detail on how to query `JSONField()` in Django here is the [docs link.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#querying-jsonfield)

Comment: Still no joy :(  I added a few more tests to orginal post.